# How are postal notifications called in Chinese?

Tags: word-requests

When the postal worker arrives at your doorstep, but can't deliver your package - usually because you are not home and it is too big for your mailbox - you receive a notification asking you to retrieve your package at the post office. How is this notification called in Chinese?

Comment: 邮件领取通知单........

Comment: They are called [「再投通知單」and「投遞通知單」](https://udn.com/news/story/7266/2543569) in Taiwan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called '邮件领取通知单' or '领取邮件通知单', and it also has other name.[image]

Comment: Thank you! Why does it say 第__號__and not __月__號？

Comment: 第_号 means your number, e.g. 第 12 号, not date.

Answer (score 1):

the hong kong post office named it as "領取郵件通知卡"

http://www.1823.gov.hk/big5/FAQ/016008/ans_01.shtm

then, there're different types of notifications, depend on the scenarios

have fun :)